# How to access enum in Unity AndroidJavaClass

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, enums

I'm a newbie to Unity. I have an Android project in Eclipse and Java class `Test` inside package `com.mytestcode`. In Test there is a nested class `Test.login` where `login` is an enum defined as `enum login {APP, WEB, APP_WEB}`. In Eclipse, I can run this fine;

```
package com.mytestcode;
import com.mytestcode.Test;
...
public testMethod(Test.login abc)
{
    if(Test.login.APP == abc){
     // do something
    }
}
```

Come to Unity, I have come to these errors

```
AndroidJavaClass test = new AndroidJavaClass("com.mytestcode.Test"); //work fine
AndroidJavaClass test2 = new AndroidJavaClass("com.mytestcode.Test.login"); //return ClassNotFound error

AndroidJavaObject test3 = new AndroidJavaClass("com.mytestcode.Test.login"); //return NoSuchFieldError error
AndroidJavaObject test4 = test.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("login.APP"); //return NoSuchFieldError error
AndroidJavObject test5 = test.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("Test.login.APP") //return NoSuchFieldError error
```

How can I access values in enum Test.login ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

my first thought is that enums are not directly convertible.. to test this:

```
//create a new enum in its own class and test
AndroidJavaClass test6 = new AndroidJavaClass("com.mytestcode.Login"); 
AndroidJavObject test7 = test6.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("Login.APP");
```

I too started on java-android heavily using enums to hold lots of data and when I got over to c#-unity, i realised that c# doesn't provide that enum-"class-type"

so I would advise to convert your enum to int until you start a new project directly on c#

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
AndroidJavaClass ajc= new    AndroidJavaClass("com.mytestcode.Test$login");
AndroidJavaObject ajo = ajc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("APP");
```

Comment: This worked for me trying to access Android's Config inside the Bitmap class, cheers!